# Display DIV's like Bee hive

Tags: html, display

What is the right way to display DIV's as a sequence of box's with no space between them ? 
[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried first.
`float: left`, `padding: 0`, `margin: 0`, `position: relative`, `border: 1px solid #663311`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use display flex:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have added **flex-wrap:wrap** to flex-container and if there are more that one line of items there is a gap between the line..., How can I avoid this gap ?

Answer (score -1):

Go for grid layout

```css
.box-wrapper {
        display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1px;
        grid-template-columns: [col1-start] 100px  [col2-start] 100px  [col3-start] 100px [col3-end];
        grid-template-rows: [row1-start] auto [row2-start] auto [row2-end];
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;

    }
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't get the downvote, as this can be achieved using grid layout also. Moreover, for 2D layout we should go for Grid layout.